# How to create csrf token in angular ui

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am using angular ui as a separate package and for the backend I am using laravel backend.Now if I bypass the csrf token in laravel I can handle the post request from separate angular package but for security I will have to use csrf in post requests.I am not using middleware.Can anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge: Tern off laravel default token behavior by commenting middleware line(As you already did).

Don't afraid with this because you can use [jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) to pass token along with the request to protecting your request/API with the middleware that comes with jwt-auth. You can get more detail from [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps).

Answer (score -1):

You could create an API in Laravel, which return CSRF Token, such as:

```
Route::get('api/token', function() {
    return Session::token();
});
```

Of course you need to add validation on the controller or middleware, etc. For example in controller:

```
public function list() {
    if (Session::token() != $request->header('X-Csrf-Token') )
        return Response::json('CSRF does not match', 400);
    // Other code
}
```

In your angularjs code, you could get the token and register it as a constant and could be injected in all angularjs HTTPRequest to the api:

```
var xhRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhRequest.open("GET", "api.yourdomain.com/api/token", false);
xhRequest.send(null);

app.constant("CSRF_TOKEN", xhRequest.responseText);

app.run(['$http', 'CSRF_TOKEN', function($http, CSRF_TOKEN) {    
    $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Csrf-Token'] = CSRF_TOKEN;
}]);
```

Comment: But the csrf token gets changed in every post request.Even if it remains constant in angular package, it will be different in laravel package.
My angular is in a different package and laravel is in a different package. Both are independent.

Comment: That's why in every HttpRequest the above code injects the CSRF token, taken from the API. The token will remain constant for the current request.                                                    I get it that your angular and laravel are different packages, that's why I proposed this answer.